# Mass Processing of E-Mails with Cognitive Text Analytics

Tags: analytics, azure-cognitive-services, bigdata

I have around 500k e-mails stored in a azure blob storage accounts (one e-mail = one document in the blob storage). Now i would like to anaylze the content of every of these e-mail with azure cognitivie text api (https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/text-analytics-api). That's working pretty good - but since i need to bulk process thousands of e-mails, i am wondering what would the be the best way to do so? Is there another azure analytics product that could help me with this? Or do i just create an azure function that's taking a document and doing the stuff?

Comment: I assume that your concern here is ratelimiting?

Comment: hi maria, thank you for your answer. no actually not. i don't want to rate limit but i want to find a way to a massively parallel execution to process thousands of e-mails...i wonder what solutions there are except using multithreading in one app...

Answer (score 0):

The Text Analytics API allows you to send up to 1000 records at a time. You can submit up to 100 requests per minute.

You can see an example on how to send a small batch [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/quickstarts/csharp). It would not be that hard to modify to send 1000 records instead of 3.

I would suggest adding some kind of delay between each batch call so that you effectively send less than 100 requests per minute.

Also, I should point out that the maximum payload of a batch request cannot be > 1MB -- so depending on the size of the emails you want to analyze, you may want to make a batch smaller than 1000 documents.

Luis Cabrera | Text Analytics PM | Microsoft Corporation